# Backbone model includes random methods and attributes

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have an backbone application that collects data from an api the data from the api looks like this,

```
{
    "id": "117",
    "name": "Another new organisation",
    "slug": "another-new-organisation",
    "information": "",
    "type": "organisation",
    "notifications": "0",
    "add_all": "0",
    "created_at": "2015-01-13 17:29:45",
    "updated_at": "2015-01-13 17:29:45",
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": "131",
            "name": "sdasdasdas",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "12312.00",
            "start_date": "2015-01-14",
            "finish_date": "2015-01-23",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:36:55",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:36:55",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "131"
            },
            "clients": null
        },
        {
            "id": "132",
            "name": "another test",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "23131.00",
            "start_date": "2015-01-07",
            "finish_date": "2015-01-16",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:38:45",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:38:45",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "132"
            },
            "clients": null
        },
        {
            "id": "133",
            "name": "yest another test",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "99999999.99",
            "start_date": "0000-00-00",
            "finish_date": "0000-00-00",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:39:25",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:39:25",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "133"
            },
            "clients": null
        },
        {
            "id": "134",
            "name": "dsadasdasdassas",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "23213.00",
            "start_date": "2015-01-21",
            "finish_date": "2015-01-29",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:40:58",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:40:58",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "134"
            },
            "clients": null
        },
        {
            "id": "135",
            "name": "wewqeqweqw",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "33432.00",
            "start_date": "2015-01-14",
            "finish_date": "2015-01-31",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:43:03",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:43:03",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "135"
            },
            "clients": null
        },
        {
            "id": "136",
            "name": "testing save",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "12321.00",
            "start_date": "2015-01-06",
            "finish_date": "2015-01-23",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:46:56",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:46:56",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "136"
            },
            "clients": null
        },
        {
            "id": "137",
            "name": "Testing again",
            "description": null,
            "total_cost": "23131.00",
            "start_date": "2015-01-13",
            "finish_date": "2015-01-29",
            "status": "1",
            "sales_person": null,
            "project_manager": null,
            "client_id": "0",
            "organisation_id": "117",
            "owner_id": null,
            "user_id": "1",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:47:28",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:47:28",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "project_id": "137"
            },
            "clients": null
        }
    ],
    "clients": [
        {
            "id": "67",
            "name": "Boom a client!",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 17:49:43",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 17:49:43",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        },
        {
            "id": "66",
            "name": "New client",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-27 12:27:59",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-27 12:27:59",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        },
        {
            "id": "71",
            "name": "sadasdasdas",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 17:58:57",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 17:58:57",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        },
        {
            "id": "68",
            "name": "Saving a client",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 17:50:31",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 17:50:31",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        },
        {
            "id": "72",
            "name": "Saving now?",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 18:02:47",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 18:02:47",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        },
        {
            "id": "70",
            "name": "What gets returned and not saved?",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 17:57:40",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 17:57:40",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        },
        {
            "id": "69",
            "name": "What gets returned?",
            "information": "",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "type": "client",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "2015-01-28 17:56:09",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 17:56:09",
            "user_id": "1",
            "owner_id": "117",
            "projects": [],
            "users": []
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "first_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "last_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "display_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "initials": "SA",
            "remember_me": null,
            "active": "1",
            "invite_code": null,
            "default_organisation": "114",
            "forgotten_code": "7bffdaa1b5b238f5ba8b13e46c53dc46",
            "login_type": "normal",
            "api_token": null,
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-28 10:48:41",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "user_id": "1",
                "is_admin": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "85",
            "email": "richard@xxxxxxxxxx",
            "first_name": "xxxxxx",
            "last_name": "xxxxxxx",
            "display_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "initials": "RB",
            "remember_me": null,
            "active": "1",
            "invite_code": null,
            "default_organisation": null,
            "forgotten_code": null,
            "login_type": "normal",
            "api_token": null,
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "117",
                "user_id": "85",
                "is_admin": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would have thought that some along the lines of this structure would be returned from my backbone model,

```
attributes: Object  
    add_all: "0"  
    clients: s
    created_at: "2014-12-16 10:16:03"  
    group_name: ""  
    id: "114"  
    information: ""  
    members: s  
    name: "Company Name"  
    notifications: "0"  
    projects: s  
    slug: "company-name"  
    teams: s  
    type: "organisation"  
    updated_at: "2015-01-29 16:04:48"  
    users: Array[2]
```

But instead I am getting the following,

[image]

What would be causing this? I read somewhere that Backbone does like receiving ID's that are not sequential could that be it?  Here is my model code,

```
    'use strict'

App.Models.Client = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: "http://" + App.API_ROOT + "/clients   ",

    defaults: {
        type:'client'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var members = this.get('users');
        //console.log(members);
        var ownerUser = this.get('owner_user');
        var ownerOrganisation = this.get('owner_organisation');
        var projects = this.get('projects');


        this.set('members', new App.Collections.Users(members));
        this.set('projects', new App.Collections.Projects(projects));

        if(ownerOrganisation == null) {
            this.set('owner', new App.Models.User(ownerUser));
        } else {
            this.set('owner', new App.Models.Organisation(ownerOrganisation));
        }
    },

});
```

So a view is created that display a list of "clients" (collection) that belong to "organisation" (model).

The organisation model looks like this,

```
    'use strict'

App.Models.Organisation = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: "http://" + App.API_ROOT + "/organisations",

    defaults: {
        group_name: '',
        type:'organisation'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        //Gets
        var members  = this.get('users');
        var projects = this.get('projects');
        var teams = this.get('teams');
        var clients = this.get('clients');
        //Sets
        if(members != undefined) {
            this.set('members', new App.Collections.Users(members));
        } else {
            this.set('members', new App.Collections.Users);
        }

        if(projects != undefined) {
            this.set('projects', new App.Collections.Projects(projects));
        } else {
                this.set('projects', new App.Collections.Projects);
        }

        if(teams != undefined) {
            this.set('teams', new App.Collections.Teams(teams));
        } else {
            this.set('teams', new App.Collections.Teams);
        }

        if(clients != undefined) {
            this.set('clients', new App.Collections.Clients(clients));
        } else {
            this.set('clients', new App.Collections.Clients);
        }

    },

});
```

And the clients collection looks like this,

```
App.Collections.Clients = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: 'http://' + App.API_ROOT + '/clients',

    model: App.Models.Client,

    initialize: function() {

    },

    search: function( filterValue ) {

        var filterThroughValue = function(data) {
            filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
            return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
                if(value != undefined) {
                    value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value);
                    //console.log(value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue));
                    return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
                }
            });
        };
        return App.Collections.filterCollection = this.filter(filterThroughValue);
    }

});
```

The data actually comes from the organisation root. And the view does all the work is here,

App.Views.ClientPanel = Backbone.View.extend({

```
tagName: 'div',

className: 'client-panel clearfix',

template: _.template( $("#tpl-client-panel").html() ),

events: {
    "click .stacked-nav a" : "triggerHeight",
    "click .js-add-client" : "addNewClient"
},

initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.model.get('clients').on('add', this.addNewClientList, this);
    App.EVENTS.on("clientAdded", function(){ $(".nav-stacked li:last a").trigger('click') }, this);
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template() );
    this.addClients();
    App.EVENTS.trigger("listBuilt");
    return this;
},

addClients: function() {
    if(this.model.get('clients').length > 0) {
        this.collection.each( this.addClient, this);
    }
},

addClient: function(model) {
    var client = new App.Views.SingleClientEntry({
        model: model,
        is_owner : this.options.is_owner,
        currentOrganisation:this.model
    });

    this.$('.nav-stacked').append( client.render().el );
},

addNewClientList: function(model) {
    if(model.get('owner_id') == this.model.get('id')) {
        var client = new App.Views.SingleClientEntry({
            model: model,
            is_owner : this.options.is_owner,
            currentOrganisation:this.model
        });

        this.$('.nav-stacked').append( client.render().el );
    }
},

addNewClient: function(e) {


    e.preventDefault();
    //$(".js-create-group[data-type=client]").trigger('click');

    this.clientModal = new App.Views.CreateClientView({
        current_organisation: this.model.get('id')
    });

    this.clientModal.render();
}
```

});

App.Views.SingleClientEntry = Backbone.View.extend({

```
tagName: 'li',

className: 'organisation-client',

template: _.template( $("#tpl-client-nav-entry").html() ),

events: {
    "click .js-change-client" : "changeClient"
},

initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
    console.log(this.model);
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('change', this.showActive, this);
    this.model.on('destroy', this.removeView, this);
    this.currentOrganisation = options.currentOrganisation;
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template({
        client: this.model.toJSON(),
        is_owner: this.options.is_owner
    }));    
    return this;
},

showActive: function() {
    this.$('a').addClass('active');
},

changeClient: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var element = $(e.currentTarget),
        modelID = element.data('id');

    $(".nav-stacked a.active").removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');

    var clientData = new App.Views.ClientData({
        model: this.currentOrganisation,
        modelID : modelID,
        is_owner: this.options.is_owner
    });

    Pops.CurrentClientID = modelID;

    $('.client-details').html( clientData.render().el );

    $('.tertiary-tabs').find('li:first').find('a').trigger('click');


},

removeView: function() {
    this.remove();
}
```

});

Comment: It appears your model is actually a collection, hence all the extra functions. Where are you doing the logging?

Comment: I am logging it all out in to my browsers console. and the api is being logged into postman for Chrome.

Comment: What I meant is, what code is doing the logging? I'd like to see the code that actually build the model and logs it

Comment: I think I am mistaken, what is actually happening is that a collection is being looped, and then models are being displayed in a view, the collection belongs to a parent model. I just dont get how the data from the API can not get parsed into the collection/model. I have updated my code.